# Add property to object based on another observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

Hi i have two arrays that come from server and i need to assign value to 2 array based on first array;
Example in first array i have nameId of a person, based on this id i need to find real name and assign it. not sure its correct reactWay to do it;

```
var names = this.nameService.query()
        .flatMap((names) => {
            return Observable.from(names);
        }).flatMap(name => {
            return Observable.combineLatest(Observable.of(name), this.nameArray, (name,nameArray) => {
                name.realName = this.nameService.getRealNamedName(name.nameId, names);
                return name;
            })
        }).toArray();


names.subscribe(names => {
 this.names = names 
})
```

EDITED:

with imperative programming i would write it like this

```
var promises = {
            people: peopleService.getPeople(),
            names: nameService.getNames()
        };

    $q.all(promises).then(result => {
        this.people = result.people.forEach(person => {
                            person.realName = result.names.find((name) => {
                                return name.id === person.id
                            })['realName']
                         })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
const realNames = [
  {'id': 2, 'realName': 'jane'},
  {'id': 1, 'realName': 'john'},
  {'id': 3, 'realName': 'joe'}
];

const peopleObservable = Rx.Observable.from([
  {id: 3, foo: 'foo3', bar: 'bar3'},
  {id: 1, foo: 'foo1', bar: 'bar1'},
  {id: 2, foo: 'foo2', bar: 'bar2'}
]);

const justNamesObservable = Rx.Observable.just(realNames);
const peopleWithNameObservable = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(peopleObservable, justNamesObservable);

var subscription = peopleWithNameObservable.subscribe(
  x => {
    const person = x[0];
    const names = x[1];
    const personWithRealName = names.find((name) => {
      return name.id === person.id
    });        
    person.realName = personWithRealName.realName        
    console.log(person);
  },
  e => {
    console.log(e);
  }, 
  () => {
    console.log('complete');
  }
);
```

You can use Observable.combineLatest.  The trick is each time a signal is emitted, it contains a *person* object and the entire *names array* where you can perform the find().

http://jsbin.com/yurufi/edit?js,console

---

Previous answer:

I'm not so clear on the requirement, but based on your question you posted (at the time of this answer), I am assuming the 2 arrays are emitted in the same order and there's a 1-to-1, then you can use Observable.zip as follow:

```
const getRealNamedName = id => {
  const realNames = {
    '1': 'john',
    '2': 'jane',
    '3': 'joe',
  };
  return realNames[id];  
}

const firstArray = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3]);
const secondArray = Rx.Observable.from([
  {id: 1, foo: 'foo1', bar: 'bar1'},
  {id: 2, foo: 'foo2', bar: 'bar2'},
  {id: 3, foo: 'foo3', bar: 'bar3'}
]);

const zipped = Rx.Observable.zip(firstArray, secondArray, (id, second) => 
  Object.assign({'realName': getRealNamedName(id)}, second)
);

zipped.subscribe(name => 
  {  
    console.log(name);  
  }, 
  e => {
    //handle error
  }, 
  () => {
    //handle complete
  }
);
```

http://jsbin.com/jiqofihoko/edit?js,console